# Why is my stock buying power lower than my cash balance?

Tags: stocks

I’m very new to trading and I am using think or swim. My cash balance is $50.90 and my stock buying power is $39.79.

Comment: I don't use TOS so I can't give you their text and verse. However, buying power is affected by various factors:  The broker's margin rate (if a margin account), unsettled trades, whether owned securities are marginable or not.  So it's insufficient information to offer anything of substance.

Comment: I rather suspect you are trading on margin, and, some of your stocks have fallen.  As a result, your margin has also fallen.  "margin" is when you put $50 on account and they give you a credit line of another $50.  As your cash value goes up and down, so does your margin.   Given the low numbers, I hope this is a simulator account or they're letting you practice with 3-digit amounts of money.  I would shudder to think you had invested serious money and didn't know you were trading on margin...

Comment: Is there a way to tell if I am trading on margin?

Comment: I may have canceled a limit order after hours if that would make a difference